# $sum arrays with the same ids in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The two documents of my collection look like this:

**First document**

```
{
 "_id" : 2055,
 "counervalues" : {
     "chcounter" : 3
     "bscounter" : 10 
  }
 "attributionvalues" :[
 {
     "id" : 1
     "conversionvalue" : 85.0
     "conversioncounter" : 6300.0
 }, 
 {
     "id" : 2
     "conversionvalue" : 25.0
     "conversioncounter" : 600
 }
}
```

**Second document**

```
{
 "_id" : 1046,
 "counervalues" : {
     "chcounter" : 23
     "bscounter" : 46 
  }
 "attributionvalues" :[
 {
     "id" : 1
     "conversionvalue" : 15.0
     "conversioncounter" : 275.0     
 }, 
 {
     "id" : 2
     "conversionvalue" : 65.0
     "conversioncounter" : 12000.0
 }
}
```

Now I want to apply the aggregation framework in order to get a new document which has a result as this:

**Result**

```
{
 "_id" : 3005,
 "counervalues" : {
     "chcounter" : 26
     "bscounter" : 56 
  }
 "attributionvalues" :[
 {
     "id" : 1
     "conversionvalue" : 100.0
     "conversioncounter" : 6575.0     
 }, 
 {
     "id" : 2
     "conversionvalue" : 90.0
     "conversioncounter" : 12600.0
 }
}
```

I started my aggregation like this:

```
db.conversion.counters.aggregate({
    $match:
    {
        "_id" : {"$gte" : 1046 , "$lte" : 2055}
    }
    $group:
    {
        cvchc: {$sum: "$counervalues.chcounter"}
        cvbsc: {$sum: "$counervalues.bscounter"}
    }
});
```

but I have trouble to match the attributionvalues according to their ids and add them.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: How did you get the `_id` in the result? It is not the sum of the previous two documents.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible in the shell - you'll need to do it in your application. You could probably write a custom mapReduce function, but again, you might as well do it in your app.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg the _id is irrelevant, I would add it through my application. I'm using the shell only to try things out faster. In my application I use spring data that supports the aggregation framework. I could do it in my app of course, but usually in mongodb you get a huge number of results and I thought aggregation framework would be faster than iterating through them in the app.

Comment: The real question I wanted to ask is will your `$group` map everything to a single `_id`? Because in your query the `$group` stage does not define an `_id`. Either way, pretty sure its not possible in pure mongo, see my second comment

Comment: @DavidGrinberg thanks. Thought mapReduce is the forerunner of aggregation framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following aggregation pipeline, should give you the desired results:

```
db.conversion.aggregate([
    { "$match": {  "_id" : { "$gte" : 1046 , "$lte" : 2055 } } },
    { "$unwind": "$attributionvalues" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$attributionvalues.id",
            "cvchc": { "$sum": "$counervalues.chcounter" },
            "cvbsc": { "$sum": "$counervalues.bscounter" },
            "avcv": { "$sum": "$attributionvalues.conversionvalue" },
            "avcc": { "$sum": "$attributionvalues.conversioncounter" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "chcounter": { "$first": "$cvchc" },
            "bscounter" : { "$first": "$cvbsc" },
            "attributionvalues": { 
                "$push": {
                    "id": "$_id",
                    "conversionvalue": "$avcv" ,
                    "conversioncounter": "$avcc" 
                }
            }        
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "counervalues": {
                "chcounter": "$chcounter",
                "bscounter": "$bscounter"
            },
            "attributionvalues": 1
        }
    } 
])
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.